# SQL query in Sparx EA returning multiple rows for tagged values

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I’m trying get an SQL query to return a single row per attribute where it don’t have a particular tagged value assigned to them, or if they do have that tagged value that it is empty.

The query below returns what I am after except it returns multiple rows because of the different tags that are assigned to them.  I’ve tried getting a group by to work to return single rows but to no avail.

```
SELECT t_package.Name AS SubPackageName
    , t_object.Name as XTable
    , t_attribute.Name as AttributeName
FROM (
      (t_package AS t_package_1 INNER JOIN (t_package INNER JOIN t_object ON t_package.Package_ID = t_object.Package_ID) ON t_package_1.Package_ID = t_package.Parent_ID)
                                INNER JOIN t_attribute ON t_object.Object_ID = t_attribute.Object_ID)
LEFT JOIN t_attributetag ON t_attribute.ID = t_attributetag.ElementID
WHERE (((t_package_1.Name)='X')
    AND ((t_object.Object_Type)='Class')
    AND ((t_attribute.Type) NOT LIKE 'tns:%') )
    AND (t_attributetag.Property <> 'dm_fieldref'
        OR (t_attributetag.Property = 'dm_fieldref'
            AND t_attributetag.VALUE is null))
ORDER BY SubPackageName, ICPTable, AttributeName;
```

Comment: It does not look like you need that for a search window. So why not break it a bit down and to the rest programmatically?

Comment: Just to double-check: are you positive that there aren't in fact multiple tagged values with the same name ("Property" column)? EA allows this, but by default hides such multiple tags in the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a **distinct**

```
SELECT distinct t_package.Name AS SubPackageName, t_object.Name as XTable...
```

Comment: Yup that worked. I was so focused on trying to get the group by to work I didn't even think to put in a Distinct clause.